# Finding Probabilities for Two-Step ML

Tags: probability, machine-learning

There are two machine learning models, A and B.

Model A classifies samples into 'O' and 'G'.
Model B classifies the samples determined to be 'O' into 'S' and 'C'.

Each model shows the probabilties of classification.

Input samples pass through model A first, and if the result is O, then they enter model B. (If not they don't)

In this case, how could I get the probabilities of classifications, G, S or C?

Comment: Define $~p(R,x)~$ naturally, where $~R \in \{A,B\}~$ and $~x \in \{O,G,S,C\}.~$ Then, $~p(A,G) = 1 - p(A,O).~$ and $~p(B,C) = 1 - p(B,S).~$    Then, (for example) the probability of being classified as $~S~$ is $~p(A,O) \times p(B,S).~$ Does this answer your question?

Comment: @user2661923 We can think of p(A,O) and p(B,S) as independent, so we multiply them, right?

Comment: Unknown - insufficient information.

Comment: Can I multiply if I don't know if they are independent? I ask because I don't know.

Comment: If you don't know that they are independent, then there is insufficient information.  Given the constraints of the problem, it is reasonable to presume that the problem composer intends that they are independent, since the $~(B,S)~$ *event* does not occur unless the $~(A,O)~$ event first occurs.

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks. Would you post it as an answer instead of here, I'll adopt it.

Comment: Not really allowed to do that, because your posted question is of low quality, with respect to [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).  The intent of my comments was to provide as little insight as possible, but still get you thinking about the problem.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks anyway